# Is there a difference between an Entity and a object?

Tags: entity-framework, object

Is there a difference between the terms Entity and Object?

Comment: Is this the .net entity framework?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Generally speaking, an *entity* is an abstract concept that's typically represented by a table in a database schema. The term *object* usually refers to in-memory data structures. An object that represents an entity may be called an *entity object* (often mapped to a row in a database table), that is it's an instance of an *entity class* (often mapped to a table).

In the .NET Framework (3.5 SP1) **an *entity* is part of an instance of the EDM (Entity Data Model)**, and is mapped to rows in one or more tables. For example, ther can be a *Customer* **entity type** that can map to a single *Customer* database table or it may also extend to a *CustomerPreferences* table as well. Using the EntityProvider, you can access entites, as if they were just rows in database tables, using eSQL. The EDM model is also known as the *conceptual layer*.

**There is another layer on top of the EDM model known as the *object layer***, where entities are materialized as EDM-mapped objects.

Answer (score 8):

An **entity** is something that exists in itself, actually or potentially, concretely or abstractly, physically or not. It needs not be of material existence.

In computer science, an **object** is a location in memory having a value and possibly referenced by an identifier.